# Core-Plot X-Axis Label Position Offset

Tags: core-plot, axis

I'm trying to shift the x-axis labels upwards. Is there a property that I can set to do that? I've tried adding some bottom padding to the plot frame, but all that does is to squeeze the entire plot upwards.

Answer (score 5):

Another question answered on Stack Overflow led me to change 'orthogonalCoordinateDecimal'.  For instance:

```
    axisSet.xAxis.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPTDecimalFromString(@"0")
```

This caused my X-axis to pass through the origin.  To raise my X-axis in relation to my graph, I changed the value to '25000', as in:

```
    axisSet.xAxis.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPTDecimalFromString(@"25000")
```

On thing to be mindful of is scale.  My values in this case ranged from 0 - 185,000 so a shift of 25,000 is approximately equivalent to a shift of 4 when the upper value of the axis is 30 (days in my case, just for example).  I was originally trying to shift the 0-185,000 axis by 5.0, and wondering why it had no effect, thinking it was a measurement of screen real estate instead of a scaled value.

Answer (score 2):

The property your looking for is axisSet.xAxis.labelOffset

Answer (score 1):

It is not totally clear, may be you need this

```
x.axisConstraints = [CPTConstraints constraintWithLowerOffset:0.0];
```

Or to display labels above axis you can use this:

```
x.tickDirection = CPTSignPositive;
```